# How to change folder in codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

is it possible to change the old site that have been built so it can be accessed by something like this :

old site become : [www.example.com/2021](http://www.example.com/2021)
and the new site : [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Simply changing the *document root* of your site may be helpful.

Comment: If the base URL of your site isn't changing then I don't see why this isn't just a change to the route config.

Answer (score 2):

You can change document root or maybe just change route in config, visit https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Open the project folder on your *new site*. Open and edit the `.env` file at the *new site's* root project directory and change the line below:

```
app.baseURL = 'http://www.example.com'
```